# In Scala 3, why can't I use Conversion for Option[Boolean] to or from java.lang.Boolean

Tags: scala

I just wrote a bunch of conversions like these to handle the problem of java nulls.

```
given Conversion[Option[scala.Boolean], java.lang.Boolean] = opBool =>
    opBool.map(Boolean.box).orNull

given Conversion[Option[scala.Short], java.lang.Short] = opShort =>
    opShort.map(Short.box).orNull
```

In general I can now compile things like this example with a Short:

```
o.setVault(n.vault)
```

However, for the case of Boolean, compile fails, saying that Option[Boolean] doesn't conform to Boolean:

```
o.setDisplayEmail(n.displayEmail)
```

Putting the same conversion in a function compiles without complaint:

```
o.setDisplayEmail(conOpSBoolToJBool(n.displayEmail))
```

Similarly, conversions in the other direction only fail for the Boolean case.

Comment: I guess there is another conversion in scope causing issues, you may debug that using your IDE. - Personal opinion, don't do this as implicit conversions but as a `asJava` conversion method instead.

Comment: Please provide a complete example. Just checked these two conversions with a method which accepts `java.lang.Boolean` and to worked.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I thought I was passing a value to a method that took a java.lang.Boolean because it was setting a nullable database field whereas it was actually (and incorrectly) coded as boolean primitive. The error messages using the simple class name "Boolean" to mean scala.Boolean, i.e. java.lang.boolean, made them indistinguishable from java.lang.Boolean, doing little to diminish my confusion.